# Take list of any type as a function parameter in Haskell (using Replit)

Tags: list, haskell, types, syntax

I'm trying to write a function in Haskell that takes a list as a parameter and returns it with the last element removed
This is the code I have:

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) =
  if null rest
    then return []
    else  hd:remLastElement rest
```

I've tested it using `[Int]` as the parameter so I know it works as intended, but I'm wondering how I can allow it to take lists of different types, like if I had a list `['apples','oranges','pears']` or a list `[2.4,7.32,1.46,4.5]`

I did some searching and in a lot of the examples I found and documentation, [a] is being used to represent a list of any type, but Replit isn't accepting that as valid syntax. I'm not sure if it's actually not valid syntax or if Replit is being silly for some reason.
I also stumbled upon forall stuff, but from what I understand that's not something built into Haskell and I would need an extension to use it.

Comment: Both answers have already pointed out you don't need `return` here. Honestly, my recommendation is: *never* use the word `return`. It's just confusing since it does something totally different than the `return` keyword in Python, Java, or literally any other language. When you need to lift a value into a monad, use [`pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:pure), which works for more types and is far less misleading. But in this example, you don't need either.

Answer (score 3):

> but I'm wondering how I can allow it to take lists of different types, like if I had a list `['apples','oranges','pears']` or a list `[2.4,7.32,1.46,4.5]`.

It already does, as long as all elements in the list have the same type, so a list of `Int`s, `String`s, etc. it works.

You only made a mistake, you should drop the `return`. Indeed, although a list is a monad, you here return a simple list, so:

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) =
  if null rest
    then []
    else hd:remLastElement rest
```

The function can also easily be simplified with pattern matching, and even made more efficient with:

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (x:xs) = go x xs
    where go _ [] = []
          go z (y:ys) = z : go y ys
```

this will prevent unpacking the same cons twice.

We can test this with floats and strings:

```
ghci> remLastElement ["apples","oranges","pears"]
["apples","oranges"]
ghci> remLastElement [2.4,7.32,1.46,4.5]
[2.4,7.32,1.46]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine your code:

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) =
  if null rest
    then return []
    else  hd:remLastElement rest
```

In this context, `return x` means `[x]`, a list containing only `x` as its unique element. Consequently, `return []` means `[[]]`, a list-of-lists containing the empty list as its unique element. This however copes with the type `[a]` that was promised by the type signature.

In general, avoid using `return` unless you are aware you are working with monads.

The fixed code is therefore

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) =
  if null rest
    then []
    else hd : remLastElement rest
```

We can still improve on this, though. Usually, you don't have to use `null`, it a minor anti-pattern. You already use pattern matching to check whether the input list is empty or not, which does not require `null`. That's great!

We can use the same technique (pattern) matching to check whether the tail (called `rest` above) is empty or not.

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement [] = []
remLastElement (hd:[]) = []
remLastElement (hd:(hd2:rest2)) = hd : remLastElement (hd2:rest2)
```

Note how we replaced the original `rest` by two new cases, `[]` and `hd2:rest2`, splitting the second equation into two new ones. Now no `if null` is needed.

We can still improve. The pattern `hd:[]` can be written as `[hd]`. Also, we can replace the whole pattern `hd2:rest2` with the original variable `rest` -- this is because equations are tried in order, so if the `[]` and `[hd]` cases are not matched, we know that `rest` must be non empty.

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement []        = []
remLastElement [hd]      = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) = hd : remLastElement rest
```

A final touch: if you turn on warnings with `-Wall` (which I strongly recommend) GHC will complain that the `hd` is not used in the second equation. To silence the warning we can replace that variable with the wildcard `_`.

```
remLastElement :: [a] -> [a]
remLastElement []        = []
remLastElement [_]       = []
remLastElement (hd:rest) = hd : remLastElement rest
```